# How to concatenate a string parameter to a Http GET command

Tags: c++, http

I am retrieving some xml data about a specific artist. What I use is boost::iostreams:

```
 boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;
    stream.connect("www.musicbrainz.org", "http");
    stream << "GET /ws/2/artist/?query=artist:madonna HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    stream << "Host: www.musicbrainz.org\r\n";
    stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
    stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
    stream.flush();

    std::cout << stream.rdbuf() << std::endl;
```

This works fine. I am getting the xml data about the artist "madonna". But I want this code to be in a method that has the artist name as a parameter and I tried this:

```
static void FetchArtistInfo(std::string artist)
{   
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;
    stream.connect("www.musicbrainz.org", "http");
    stream << "GET /ws/2/artist/?query=artist:";
    stream << artist;
    stream << " ";
    stream << "HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    //stream << url;
    stream << "Host: www.musicbrainz.org\r\n";
    stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
    stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
    stream.flush();

    std::cout << stream.rdbuf() << std::endl;
}
```

But writing the stream like that doesn't retrieve the data. I always get a "Forbidden" xml file.

Any ideas how to construct my stream to work for any artist given in the string parameter ?

Comment: have you verified the contents of the param artist ?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. i also tried other methods of concatenate the all GET command into a string and attached it to the stream, but nothing seems to works, only if I send the GET commands as a plain string.Like in the first example